# Is there a way for a new window to communicate with the window that spawned it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I have an application that asks a user to login with Reddit. When they accept, it opens a new window (call it SpawnedWindow), Reddit asks them if they want to connect, and when they do, SpawnedWindow redirects to a GET endpoint on my server with the success/failure information. My server will do some computation to figure out if the auth was really successful, and if it is, it will send an "ok" (as a response to the GET request) to SpawnedWindow.

I want the original page to detect this "okay" and continue with user onboarding. How might I communicate this between the new window and the original window?

If you're familiar with "login with Google" buttons: as we know, there's a popup, and depending on the result of authentication, the main page will have dynamic behavior (based on the login being successful or not). This is essentially what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Can't tell - do you control both documents? If so, use inter-window messaging. Standard messaging API using `window.opener` and handle returned from `window.open()` - if you don't control the documents you're out of luck.

Comment: What do you open on Reddit that results in them being asked if they want to login? Can you share an example URL?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm using Reddit OAuth on my site, which will ask the user to give my app permission to access their account data: https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#authorization

Comment: @RandyCasburn Are you familiar with how "login with google" prompts work? There's a popup, and depending on the result of authentication, the main page will have dynamic behavior. This is essentially what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Got it. then you are out of luck. Since a document that you own from your site did not open the other window, you will be unable to message between them. But, OAuth provides for a return URL that you can specify. Generally, once logged in, the workflow would be to return to the "onboarding" page. There, you will be able to detect if the user is logged in or not to continue the process.

Comment: `window.opener.postMessage` should still work

Comment: @RandyCasburn To be clear: I do open the window because I initiate the authentication with a `window.open('reddit.com/api/v1/authorize')`. However, I "lose control of the document" in the sense that the destination site is controlled by reddit, not me, and only comes back to a page owned by me upon successful authentication.

Comment: In that case, CertainPerformance has your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API (and many APIs which have a similar authorization process) provides a `redirect_uri` that the user will be redirected to after authorization succeeds. You can pass a `redirect_url` query parameter that goes to a page on your site. This way, once authorization succeeds, the newly opened page (on your site, that Google has redirected the popup to) can communicate to the original page (on your site).

One way to do this is with a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) - open a channel on your original page, and wait for a message. On the new page, open the same channel and send a message, and the old page can listen for the message.

Another option would be to use Local Storage. On the original page, listen for [storage change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_storageevent) events. On the new page, change storage so as to fire the event.